# How do I quickly find the duplicate questions I'm searching for when flagging/closing?

Tags: support, duplicates, searching

I don't like the search box when I'm flagging for a duplicate, because I don't know the exact names of the big questions. Even if I use very relevant keywords, the question that I want to pick is always lost somewhere in the list and I have to scroll down and search for it.

How do you guys find and pick the duplicates quickly?

**Example**: I want to flag a question as a duplicate of the oh-so-famous *How to Install Broadcom Drivers* question, but when I search "broadcom drivers", it's not at the top of the list (and depending on the question, it's sometimes not even ***in*** the list). I always forget the exact name of the question too. How do I quickly search for it?

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What I usually do is use the `score:#` option.

For example: search for `broadcom drivers score:10`, or even shorter, just `broadcom score:10`. Take a look at this:

[image]

`score:10` means "show me questions with a score of 10 or more". This removes those low-score questions from the list, making it easier to spot the question you're looking for.

Of course, you don't always have to use the number `10`; this is just an example. If you know the question is really popular and has, let's say, 90 upvotes, then you could use a higher number.

Example:

Searching for `uefi` only, gives us:

[image]

But searching for `uefi score:40` gives us:

[image]

If, however, you're searching for a question that has a relatively low score, you'll need to do some trial-and-error, using `score:3` for example, to exclude other low voted questions.

An alternative would be to have those questions in your favorites, and use the option `infavorites:mine`, which will only search for questions in your favorites.

Comment: Nice! Is all good and cozy. Just one question... why you still have close votes?