# Could be possible duplicates arranged by votes in addition to default order?

Tags: feature-request, close-dialog

When I find duplicate question, for example [Will not allow me to install playonlinux! Says I have 'held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/432969/will-not-allow-me-to-install-playonlinux-says-i-have-held-broken-packages-pl)
and flag them, the system shows me the list of possible answers like this:

[image: screenshot]

When I click on [Install packages with unmet dependencies](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25930/install-packages-with-unmet-dependencies) I receive the screen with desired link:
[How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)

[image: screenshot]

But I want that the second link would be seen before any duplicates

Another example is https://askubuntu.com/questions/311626/the-black-screen: I want to see [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it) when I type "black screen", but get duplicate question on first place.

It is quite annoying to copy correct link to the buffer then to paste it inside search string. So I think about ordering by votes.

Comment: BTW, it's not a duplicated, heck is not even an answerable question.

Comment: I think this could help http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/7293/169736

Comment: Yes, this is really helpful. Thanks!

Comment: This is a feature request, the other post is a support question, not duplicates.