# The duplicate question search engine while closing a question is not useful

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Whenever I try to close a question as duplicate, a floating window pops up which is a mini search engine to find duplicate question.

But it is never helpful(except in exceptional cases). For example, when I tried to search for the `unmet dependencies` question with following terms

```
dependency
unmet dependency
unmet dependencies
how to resolve unmet dependencies
```

none returned the question I was searching for. Finally, I had to put part of the exact title

```
how do I resolve unmet dependencies
```

to get the question I was searching for. This happens everytime I try to close a question.

So I think this thing needs some serious makeover.

<sub>BTW this is somewhat related  to 
[How do I quickly find the duplicate questions I'm searching for when flagging/closing?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/7293/184942)</sub>

Comment: I agree. Adding `score:10` helps sometimes, but in general this search thing is almost entirely useless.

Comment: I always use google with "site=askubuntu.com"...

Comment: The search engine is not useful. Period.

Comment: @muru See my answer - it may be of interest to you.

Comment: Cross site duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187773/link-up-the-excellent-search-engine-that-gives-questions-that-may-already-have

Comment: @Seth so can/will anything be done about this?

Answer (score 2):

This has been discussed elsewhere already:

- [Why is duplicate search still awful?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289364/why-is-duplicate-search-still-awfu)   on Meta Stack Overflow
- [Help us find duplicates efficiently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/232242/help-us-find-duplicates-efficiently) on MSE
- ...

Search (and not just dupe search !) is just bad.

You could use Google with `site:askubuntu.com`,  put `score:10` in dupefinder box, just bookmark the questions which you use as duplicate most often so you have the link, or something else.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187773/link-up-the-excellent-search-engine-that-gives-questions-that-may-already-have